# Installing SCM provider for use with m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, m2e, eclipse-mars

When I try to materialize a Maven Project, it silently fails in Eclipse and gives a log entry

!MESSAGE SCM provider is not available for scm:svn:http://do1s...

After some googling and some dead links it is still not clear to me how to install such a provider (or tell m2e or Eclipse about it). I have a working Subclipse plugin in Eclipse and a working command line installation of svn.

Can anybody give me a hint what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install SCM providers here: Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Discovery -> Open Catalog

Scroll down to "m2e Team providers" there should be something like m2e-subversive.

Comment: Are "connectors" and "providers" the same?

Comment: In general not but here they are.

Comment: By the way: Do you know if there is any chance of changing the Catalog url to a different one (our company is really strict about allowing downloads from the internet)?

Comment: No, but maybe you can find out how to install that provider manually.